# Can a machine with dual processors work as two individual servers?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I was wondering if a physical machine with a two processor motherboard and two  processors can operate as two individual  servers in one machine.

For example: 
server A would run a Linux environment, server B would run windows server 2016.

They of course would have their own storage bay and their own network adapters.

An example machine would be the HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen9.

Is this even possible in general?
As in, are there motherboards/processors that support this?

If this is possible, would you be able to switch the display from one to the other?

And even more specific, if both would run VMWare, could they operate in a High-Availability Cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You cant "cut" a machine down the middle.  An operating system will have to control the whole environment.  However, once the OS is installed, you can limit its hardware usage.  You could limit the host OS to one CPU (or even individual cores), some storage, assign it specific network adapters, etc. and give the remaining to a virtual machine.  Of course, this means if the host machine were to go down, the virtual machine will go down, as well.

However, when it comes to virtual machines, there are a lot of options.  Various VM hypervisors can run in high availability modes, where you can move entire virtual machines, nearly on the fly to different host machines.  Of course this requires multiple servers and in some cases, specialized hardware, like a NAS.  This is beyond the scope of this question, though.

Comment: Are there any systems that come close to this question? Like.. Are there systems that maybe house 2 machines in one case and it magically fits into a 1U or 2U rack?

Comment: Not that I know if.  There *may* be some custom server build like this, but I dont know of any.  A host OS/hypervisor with VM(s) is the closest you can get.

Comment: The Intel Buchanan Pass Refresh servers https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/motherboards/server-motherboards/server-board-s2600bp-brief.html have multiple computing modules, each module with two Xeon CPUs, with independent RAM and SSDs and/or HDDs. Four modules fit into one 2U rack-mount chassis.

Comment: @K7AAY interesting.  I havent seen blade servers this small.